# python tkinter directories not displaying correctly in grid view

Tags: python, button, gridview, directory, tkinter

I am trying to display a mounted file systems directories for browsing. I am storing directories inside of a list and then assigning them to a button each. The problem I am having is that only one button appears when I run the program. Library is the final directory and it is the only one that is printing out. I first thought that it could be the window size as it only accommodated enough size for one button so I changed the size of the window and the problem remained.

I think the problem may be in the code used to create the button itself, namely the master part. Each time this is run wouldn't the previous master button just be replaced by the new one? How would I get around this if this is the case?

I also know that my code for the placing of the buttons will not work correctly right now. After a few buttons have been placed I want to start on a new row and repeat but right now it will only go down to the third row and no further. I can't seem to think of a good way to keep increasing the rows without the use of minimal coding.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: latin-1

import os
from Tkinter import *

a=[]
b=[]
row = 0
column = 0

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/mnt/Backups.backupdb/stuart dent\xe2\x80\x99s MacBook Pro'):
    b = dirnames
    a = filenames

master = Tk()
master.geometry("500x500")
for dirnames in b:
    Button(master, width=8, height=4, text=b).grid(row=row, column=column, padx=10, sticky=W)
    column = column + 2
    if column == 10:
        row = 3
        column = 0
    break

mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't really know tkinter, but you're setting row=3 after getting to column index 10. All the rest of the buttons would be placed in row 3 so.. Also, you have buttons of width 8 and height 4, and you're only going 10 accross and 3 down. Maybe they overlap?

Comment: sounds as if i have another problem. thank you i will deal with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ask yourself the question "what is b at the point I do 'for dirnames in b'?". If you can't figure that out by following the logic (which can sometimes be hard because of assumptions you unconsciously make), add a print statement immediately before the second "for".

In the first for loop you are overwriting the data on each iteration, throwing away any data that came before. By the time that loop is done, `b` only contains the data for the last folder. Thus, when you finally get to the loop to create the buttons, you only have whatever dirnames were in the last folder in your main folder.

Comment: yes I see where I have gone wrong now, thank you. making assumptions is a big problem for me